# Binding varargs using android databinding library

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am trying to write a custom setter for SwipeRefreshLayout's

`setColorScheme(int... colors)`.

But it seems that its parameter is varargs.

I can only bind a single color now like the following:

```
   @BindingAdapter("app:colorSchemeResources") 
    public static void bindRefreshColor(SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout,  int colorResId) {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(colorResId);
    }
```

xml:

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:colorSchemeResources ="@{@color/primary}"
                />
```

My question is:

How can I write a custom setter for varargs?

How to bind varargs in the xml file?

Comment: please share some code what have you tried so far. xml file too.

Comment: sure, I have updated the question. I can only bind a single color by far.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

Specify an integer array containing the colors you want in your colors.xml for example:

```
    <integer-array name="color_scheme" >
       <item>@color/first_color</item>
        <item>@color/second_color</item>
    </integer-array>
```

Change your bindingadapter like this:

```
    @BindingAdapter("app:colorSchemeResources")
    public static void bindRefreshColor(SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout, int[] colorResIds) {
    swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(colorResIds);
    }
```

And reference your array in your view:

```
        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:colorSchemeResources ="@{@intArray/color_scheme}"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Comment: Thanks, it woks like a charm.The intArray is just what I want.

Comment: Where did you place integer-array name="color_scheme" ?

Comment: @kondal you can put it in values/colors etc xmls